# Dynamic pointer array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, declaration

Recently this declaration thing is confusing me.
There are two different files, one is `score.cpp` and the other is`curve1.cpp`. The second class `Curve1` is inherited from the first class `Score`.

In `score.cpp`, I have declared:

`ipScore = new int[getSize()];`.

This is compiling fine and working without any issues. But when in `curve1.cpp`, I declare another variable:

`new_ipScore = new int[getSize()];`

It's saying that `'new_ipScore' : undeclared identifier` and

`'=' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int'`

What's the problem here? Anyone can help?

Comment: Did you declare `new_ipScore`?

Comment: Isn't `new_ipScore = new int[getSize()];` the declaration? If it's not, then why `ipScore = new int[getSize()];` is working without any errors? Thanks

Comment: `ipScore` is probably declared. No, `new_ipScore = new int[getSize()];` isn't a declaration, it's an assignment to an already declared variable. `int* new_ipScore = ...` would be a declaration + initialization.

Comment: Stuuuuupid MEEEEEEE. Yes it was already declared in private of class `Score` Haha thanks any way ;) *huff*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `new_ipScore` is not declared. Please declare it. I have noticed that you have followed object-oriented paradigm. So maybe `ipScore` is declared in `private` of a class? A wild guess would be `Score` class. So please check before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you asking us if the compiler has already said what is the problem?!

**'new_ipScore' : undeclared identifier**

Where is this identifier declared? We do not see what the type of the identifier is. Maybe you can say this yourself?

Comment: Yes Mr. Vlad, `ipScore` was already declared in private of class `Score` while `new_ipScore` was not. Stupid me..

Comment: @Silver Falcon We could only repeat what the compiler already said adding some words.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> new_ipScore = new int[getSize()];
> ```
>
> It's saying that `'new_ipScore' : undeclared identifier` and
>
> ```
> '=' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int'
> ```

With `new int[...]` you dynamically allocate an array of integers on the heap. The return value is a pointer to the first item in this array, i.e. `int*`.

Probably you haven't defined the `new_ipScore` variable in your code, so the compiler has no idea about that; in fact, the compiler is complaining: `'new_ipScore' : undeclared identifier`.

Just define `new_ipScore` as an `int*`.

Note also that in *modern* C++, the usual way of managing arrays is by using `std::vector`, in your case `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Thanks man. My stupidity that `ipScore` was already declared in private of class `Score`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SilverFalcon: No problem. Everyone of us has done (and will do) wrong things in code: they are called bugs :)